# How do I show a statement is a tautology in the Booleans algebra

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I want to show through Boolean algebra that the statement 
$$\neg Q\Rightarrow (R\Rightarrow \neg (P\land Q))$$
is equivalent to the tautology $Q\lor(\neg Q)$?

Answer (score 5):

Don't know exactly what you mean by "Boolean algebra", given that implications are not usually part of the language of Boolean algebras. If I translate $A\Rightarrow B$ to the logically equivalent $\neg A \lor B$, then it is straightforward:

\begin{align*}
\neg Q\Rightarrow (R\Rightarrow (\neg (P\land Q)) &\equiv \neg(\neg Q)\lor (R\Rightarrow (\neg (P\land Q)))\\
&\equiv Q \lor (\neg R \lor (\neg(P\land Q)))\\
&\equiv Q\lor (\neg R \lor (\neg P \lor \neg Q))\\
&\equiv Q \lor \neg R \lor \neg P \lor \neg Q\\
&\equiv (Q\lor \neg Q) \lor (R\lor \neg P)\\
&\equiv Q\lor \neg Q.
\end{align*}

**Added.** In the comments you ask how to prove it by contradiction: here we use the fact that $\neg(A\Rightarrow B) \equiv A\land \neg B$.

\begin{align*}
\neg\Bigl(\neg Q\Rightarrow (R\Rightarrow (\neg (P\land Q))\Bigr) &\equiv
\neg Q \land \neg\Bigl(R\Rightarrow (\neg (P\land Q))\Bigr)\\
&\equiv \neg Q \land \Bigl( R \land \neg(\neg(P\land Q))\Bigr)\\
&\equiv \neg Q \land (R \land (P\land Q))\\
&\equiv \neg Q \land R \land P \land Q\\
&\equiv (\neg Q\land Q) \land R \land P\\
&\equiv (\neg Q\land Q).
\end{align*}
Since the negation of the proposition is equivalent to a contradiction, the original proposition is a tautology, i.e., true.

Comment: Yes that P and Q are bollean variables! If we then say P is the value of 0 and Q is the value of 1, is it possible to define this in a table as the same prinsiple like the truthtable.

Comment: Yes that P and Q are bollean variables! If we then say P is the value of 0 and Q is the value of 1, is it possible to define this in a table as the same prinsiple like the truthtable.

Comment: @Learningbyasking: I'm sorry, but I do not understand what you are asking in this comment.

Comment: My mistake, I confused this with something else.

If we now should take the statement: (not Q => (R  => not (P and Q)) and show it by proof of contradiction. How is this done, my teaching book show a quite difficult example where I understand only the fist part of the Example.  Do you have any good books that you also advice me to read?

Comment: @Learningbyasking: Are you asking how one would prove it is true by contradiction?

Comment: Yes, Since I have allready prooven by truth table that its a tautology. So want to give an example by contradiction.

Comment: @Learningbyasking: Done.

Comment: Arturo, the implication is commonly used with Boolean algebras as an added operator. Your interpretation is correct.

Comment: Thank you, now I am back on track, with the examples shown in my book